# Select specific div class using nth-child

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/kV7Uq/1/

```
.productList div.grid:nth-child(4n+5){
clear:left;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a 4 column grid. The above code used in the fiddle seems to be just fine - but if you look at that fiddle there is no 4 column grid.

```
<div class="pageNav"></div>
<div class="pageHeading"></div>
```

The above two divs that are also child divs of the container div, and located prior to the grid divs are causing a conflict. If those two divs are removed, the grid comes out just fine. I'm not sure if this is even fixable, please help - thank you.

Comment: so what's the exact shape you want, it's unclear here because you have the `pageNav` and `pageHeading`

Comment: You can wrap the other divs .pageNav and .pageHeading in new div and .grid divs in another div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just offset it by 2 to compensate for those divs.  Instead of `+5`, use `+3`.

```
.productList div.grid:nth-child(4n+3){
    clear:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kV7Uq/2/

If you don't want the very first box to have the `clear: left` then it would be `+7`.

Comment: That fixed it right up :D I clearly had a very poor understanding of how the (an+b) actually works, and now you've cleared that up for me as well! Thanks friend!